# C++ pointers - delete operation on array pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

While I was using delete operator on pointers, I saw something that I could not understand. I think it is best to show it on an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int* p = new int[5]{3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    cout << p[0] << p[1] << p[2] << p[3] << p[4] << '\n';

    delete[] p;

    cout << p[0] << p[1] << p[2] << p[3] << p[4] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
34567
00567
```

After the delete operation why first two elements turned to zeros? Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your replies.

Comment: That my friend is UB. There is no reason to use deleted pointers.

Comment: Undefined Behavior means *anything* can happen. Or not. There is no general explanation of the observed behavior in such a case, and although sometimes one can reasonable conclude what's going on under the hood, that's not possible in the current case.

Comment: delete operation does not turn elements to zero, it destroys array elements (which is noop in case of `int`) deallocates memory so afterwards those elements become unreachable and deleted pointer value becomes invalid. So the second print run in this case is just a dereferencing of invalid pointer leading to Undefined behavior.

Comment: @DimChtz Doing so will still lead to UB.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/1968

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2):

```
 delete[] p;

 cout << p[0] << p[1] << p[2] << p[3] << p[4] << endl;
```

The moment you use `p` after calling `delete[]` on it, it's undefined behavior. As the wording says the behavior is undefined so questioning why x or y happens is pointless as this is uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to pay for what you don't need in C++.

Why would you expect released memory to be zeroed? `delete` just marks the memory as not used anymore, there's no need to zero it since you can't use it anyway without invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you 'delete' a pointer or variable, there's no reason for it to be set to '0'.
By deleting the array you simply tell the computer that it can use the given space freely. The interesting question is not why the rest of the values persist, but actually why are the 2 first ones are set to '0', and the answer could really be anything

Answer (score -1):

System do not have to clear this memory with zeroes.

delete[] just means you do not not need this memory anymore and you return this memory to the system. System  marked this memory as free and will overwrite it with new data sometime in future.